# Changing number of decimal places of a String variable within a Vector Layer using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, string, decimal-points

I have earthquake data and within the data, there are magnitude, longitude and latitude values. However, these values have around 6/7 decimal places but I would like to only have 2 decimal places for each value, when I export my map. I add the earthquake event through QgsVectorLayer rather than a CSV format when using python and I can access features such as magnitude, longitude and latitude, by using `feat['magnitude'])`, as can be seen below:
[image]

I then add each feature to the layout exporter, ready to export. I have tried various ways to only get 2 decimal places on each feature but non have prevailed as of yet. The ways I have tried are: `to_real(ID)`, `format_number(ID, decimal place)`, `float(ID)`, `round($ID, decimal places)` and `layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("fieldname",  QVariant.String, "String", 10, 2)])`. I may have done part of the code wrong though, hence why it did not work. Each feature is within a string variable but I can not seem to find a way how to convert to double or real. A small snippet of my map is included below where the values of magnitude, longitude and latitude can be seen, so that I would like each value to say 4.39 (Mag), -72.02 (Long) and 6.40 (Lat). Hope this makes sense.
[image]

Comment: Please provide information on the "various ways" you tried, especially code examples.

Comment: Just updated my answer to the ways I have tried

Comment: I now am confused whether this is about changing the data, or changing the display of the values, as well as why there is the python tag, since you seem to care about the display in the map composer?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Basically, I would like the end result so that the display of the values on the map composer has 2 decimal places for each value. Whether that is changing the data so that when I add each feature to the layout, the data will already have 2 decimal places, then adding the data or if it is adding the data first and then changing the number of decimal places on the display of the map composer, either one works for me. As long as the values have 2 decimal places. I added a python tag as I am using the python console in QGIS to get this result. Hope this helps?

Comment: The correct syntax using the field calculator would be `round(to_real("field-name"),2)` - while "field name" should be exchanged with some syntax for the currently chosen/visible feature.

Comment: Within the python console, it says that NameError: name 'to_real' is not defined

Comment: Replace `feat['magnitude']` with `str(round(feat['magnitude'], 2))`. PS: tested :)

Comment: Hi @ThomasG77, sorry but it comes up with the error - TypeError: type str doesn't define __round__ method. Any ideas?

Comment: and `str(round(str(feat['LONGITUDE']), 2))` ? It seems you magnitude value in the feature is a string

Comment: Still the same error unfortunately. Yes, my magnitude, latitude and longitude values are all in a string format... is there a piece of code I can write to convert string to double or real and then round? Thanks

Comment: The piece above does it using a feature like you but without issue do so I don't know what change in your context that break the same code I'm able to run successfully on my sample to debug your issue

Comment: Ohhh how strange that it works for you but not in my code... is it because I add through a vector layer rather than a delimited text layer?

Comment: # Lines to simplify the debug. Execute the 2 statements in PyQGIS console `feat = next(iface.activeLayer().getFeatures())` and `print(str(round(float(feat['magnitude']), 2)))` `iface.activeLayer()` can be replace by `layer` in your code if necessary

Comment: I forgot the conversion from string to float before rounding. Is it better?

Comment: So, I have replaced line 313 in my code with 'feat = next(iface.activeLayer().getFeatures())' and added in 'print(str(round(float(feat['magnitude']), 2)))' below it but now it comes with the error - KeyError: 'magnitude' on the second line of code you suggested... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119368/discussion-between-liamhems-and-thomasg77).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit: definitive answer**

```py
mag.setText("Magnitude: " + str(round(float(feat['magnitude']), 2)))
```

**Archived answer for people using Atlas**

You can find below a sample to illustrate. This sample is using an existing `QgsLayoutItemLabel` you must select manually to work instead of one you created like your sample. I'm also in the context of an atlas to loop each feature.

```
layout_name = 'your_layout_name'
project = QgsProject.instance()
projectLayoutManager = project.layoutManager()
layout = projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(layout_name)


# You should select your label layout item before runnong this line of code
existing_layout_item_label = layout.selectedLayoutItems()[0]

text = "[% attribute(@atlas_feature ,'NAME')%]\nRounded lat : [%round(to_real(attribute(@atlas_feature ,'LATITUDE')),2)%]"
existing_layout_item_label.setText(text)

layout.refresh()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not using an Atlas feature. I can not seem to find a way using my code to use: [%round(to_real(attribute(@atlas_feature ,'LATITUDE')),2)%], as it just prints this statement rather than rounding latitude to 2 decimal places.